# java.lang.NullPointerException: rvHobbies must not be null

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Estyo creando un RecyclerView conectado a Firebase, pero me sale el siguiente eror:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: rvHobbies must not be null

He probado poniendo this.context en el LinearLayoutManager, pero sigue sin funcionar. Dejo aquí el código del fragmento:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var adapter:MainAdapter
private val ViewModels : MainViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    adapter = MainAdapter(activity)
    rvHobbies.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
    rvHobbies.adapter = adapter
    observeData()

}

fun observeData(){
    shimmer_view_container.startShimmer()
    ViewModels.fetchUserData().observe(this, Observer {
        shimmer_view_container.stopShimmer()
        shimmer_view_container.hideShimmer()
        shimmer_view_container.visibility = View.GONE
        adapter.setListData(it)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
}



override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?

): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `onCreate` se ejecuta antes del `onCreateView` que es dónde se infla el layout. Esto quiere decir que dentro `onCreate` no puedes acceder al recyclerView ni a ningún otro elemento del layout. Ese tipo de cosas debes hacerlas en el método `onViewCreated`

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    adapter = MainAdapter(activity)
    rvHobbies.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
    rvHobbies.adapter = adapter
    observeData()
}
```